# Restore MATE Applications menu without mozo

Tags: mate

While attempting to edit the MATE menu via mozo, I tried to drag a folder to a different position, and the next thing I knew was that the entire menu was empty. When I now open the Applications menu, I get a completely empty menu. When I try to edit it, mozo crashes instantly.

I have the classic layout (with Applications, Places and System menus—the latter two are OK, just Application is empty.)

How can I restore my menus (preferably to what I had last, or default if all else fails)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Menu settings are stored in `~/.config/menus`, the Applications menu residing in `mate-applications.menu`.

The file is an XML file. I my case, it seems to have gotten corrupted by inserting a tree of nested `<Menu>` items, with (among others) a `<Move>` item at its bottom.

Removing that tree and saving fixed this. The change was reflected in the menu instantly.

If the corruption is less obvious, alternatives are:

- Replace the file from backup (if available)
- Move it away and see if it gets recreated (or create a fresh user account and copy it over from there), then copy in salvaged snippets from the backup one-by-one, verifying after each step that everything still works.

PS: I’ve filed a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mate/+bug/1768975) for the underlying data corruption issue.

Answer (score 2):

Just for your information - MATE has well-built own menu editor.
It is called Mozo and maybe installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install mozo
```

It looks like:

[image: mozo on MATE]

quote from its help:

> #### Customizing the Panel Menubar
>
> You can modify the contents of the following menus:
>
> - *Applications* menu
> - *System ▸ Preferences* submenu
> - *System ▸ Administration* submenu
>
> To edit the items in these menus, right-click on the panel menubar, and choose *Edit Menus*. The *Menu Layout* window opens.
>
> The *Menu Layout* window lists the menus in the left pane. Click on the expander arrows to show or hide submenus. Choose a menu in the left pane to see its items listed in the right pane.
>
> To remove an item from a menu, deselect it in the list. The item can be added back to the menu by selecting it once again.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, in fact it was mozo, not alacarte, that I’d been using and which had given me the error described (just checked in the process list). I’ve updated the question.